# how to rotate scale group ungroup shape without use matrix

Tags: java

hello i want rotate scaliing group ungroup and resize shape in java?
i think based on my move function for rotate and scaling but i'm not sure how make it
oh please help me for group and ungroup and resize

my move and rotate functions

```
@Override
public void move(Point begin, Point end) 
{
    Rectangle r=new Rectangle(this.getR().x+(end.x-begin.x),this.getR().y+(end.y-begin.y),this.getR().width,this.getR().height);
    this.setR(r);
}

@Override
public void rotate(Point begin,Point end) 
{
    Rectangle r=new Rectangle(this.getR().x-(end.x+getR().height/2),getR().y+(end.y-getR().width/2),this.getR().width,this.getR().height);
    //Rectangle r=new Rectangle(this.getR().x+(end.x*getR().width),this.getR().y+(end.y*getR().width),this.getR().width,this.getR().height);
    this.setR(r);
    //what?

}
```

Comment: I think googling : resize shapes java, group shapes java,and ungroup shapes java would solve your problem

Comment: i googling  but i  do not found solved my problem

Comment: did you try to search github.com ?

Comment: yes and do not found noting in github for me

Comment: it really surprises me, hmmmm well you have three questions : group , ungroup , resize. ask these in three seperate questions and don't forget to mention that you googled and searched in github without luck.

Comment: and sorry but I don't know much about Gui in java :)